# Pandas read_csv and remove daylight saving

Tags: python, pandas, python-dateutil

I have a 312.5MB csv file containing EURUSD 1min OHLC data from 27/7/2003 to date, but the dates are all adjusted for daylight saving, meaning I get duplicates and gaps.

Seeing as it's such a big file the default date parser was way too slow, so I did this:

```
tizo = dateutil.tz.tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/GB')
def date_parse_1min(s):
    return datetime(int(s[6:10]), 
                    int(s[3:5]), 
                    int(s[0:2]), 
                    int(s[11:13]),
                    int(s[14:16]),tzinfo=tizo)

df = read_csv("EURUSD_1m_clean_w_header.csv",index_col=0,parse_dates=True, date_parser=date_parse_1min)

#verify that it's got the tz right:
df.index
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'toordinal'" in 'pandas.tslib._localize_tso' ignored
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'toordinal'" in 'pandas.tslib._localize_tso' ignored
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2003-07-26 23:00:00, ..., 2012-12-15 23:59:00]
Length: 4938660, Freq: None, Timezone: tzfile('/usr/share/zoneinfo/GB')
```

No idea why there are attribute errors there.

```
df.index.get_duplicates()
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2003-10-26 01:00:00, ..., 2012-10-28 01:59:00]
Length: 600, Freq: None, Timezone: None
df1 = df.tz_convert('GMT')
df1.index.get_duplicates()
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2003-10-26 01:00:00, ..., 2012-10-28 01:59:00]
Length: 600, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

How can I get pandas to remove the daylight saving offset? Obviously I could work out the right integer indexes that need changing and do it like that, but there must be a better way.

Comment: Could you set the index to be the `date_range` with frequency every minute, then check any differences are only off by an hour from DST?

Comment: I could do something like that perhaps, although I'd have to take in to account all the missing minutes from the data (over every weekend etc.)

Answer (score 0):

If you take the first and last duplicate value of each year and shift the data in-between by an hour, that should be the easiest way of correcting the issue. You'll obviously have to take into account that the first data points start in daylight savings.

Comment: The first day isn't a duplicate, it's a 1 hour gap, seeing as the clocks go forward then.

I could do that, but it wouldn't be very robust seeing as it would lock on to any 1 hour gap that happens to exist in the data